# jQuery KeyUp and Click

Tags: jquery, click, onkeyup

I was wondering how you can do `.keyup()` and `.click()` for the same `#id`?

i.e. essentially I want to validate the `#id` when both the user attempts to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> or hits the `#search` button.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$('#foo').bind('click keyup', function(event) {
  ...
```

You'll have to add some logic, as the event type changes, but it should work with enough `if` blocks.

Comment: I initially thought this too, but it doesn't look like the OP really wants to bind multiple events to a DOM object, but instead have multiple events on multiple objects invoke the same code.

Comment: Ah, that seems right. @Neal's answer is more appropriate then.

Comment: hi - yeah thanks a lot. the aim is to invoke multiple events on multiple objects ?

Comment: If it's the same event, you can add multiple objects to the selector: `$('#foo, #bar, #baz').bind('click keyup mouseover'), function(...`

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do:

```
        $(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
            if (objEvent.keyCode == 13) {  //clicked enter
                 $('#search').click(); //do click
            }
        })

        $("#search").click(function(e){/*click fn*/})
```

Will run the click on enter press

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#id").click(validate).keyup(function(event)
{
    if (event.keyCode == '13') validate();
});
function validate() { ... validate $(this).val(); ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for something like this:

```
function validate(element) {
     // your validation stuff goes here
}

$('#id').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {  
        validate(this);
    }
}).click(function() {
    validate(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The new jQuery offers the which property on the event to check which key was pressed so yo can do something like this now:

```
$(#id").on('keyup',function(e){
    if (e.which==13 || e.which==9) doSomething(this); //Enter or Tab key
});
```

Answer (score 0):

function checkEnter(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {

```
            if (!(date_regex.test(event.target.value))) {
                event.target.value = '';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves problem. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)